# Resume Application in Original State

Tags: android

So here's the setup... I have an application that streams a live radio station from a URL. I currently have it so that the stream still resumes playing after the user has pressed the back button. As of current, the only way to get back into the application is to press and hold the home button then select the app. I would like it so that the application can be accessed more easily by placing it in the notification panel. I am able to achieve this setup, however, the notification panel insists on creating a new activity.  This overwrites the previous activity making it impossible to stop the stream or quite the application (without having to force close). I am looking for a way to get the application into the notification panel, and when pressed, bring back the EXACT state, so that the stream and application can be manipulated as if it has never been exited. Here is what I have for the showNotification method...

```
private void showNotification() {
    CharSequence text = "My Positive Edge";
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationIntent = new Intent(context, NewMPEStreamImpl.class);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.klrc_icon, text, System.currentTimeMillis());
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "My Positive Edge",this.isPlaying, contentIntent);
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT | Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;    
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}
```

Is this the service I should be calling for what I'm wanting to do, or do I need something completely different?

Answer (score 0):

First off, if i have got your question right -

> "I am looking for a way to get the application into the notification
>   panel, and when pressed, bring back the EXACT state"

if this is what you are trying to achieve and for this you are taking the activity to notification and resuming back "NewMPEStreamImpl.class" I guess it might not be a better Idea.

Let me make it clear,

> Status bar Notifications should be used for any case in which a
>   background service needs to alert the user about an event that
>   requires a response.

Read the [Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) please.

If you are looking to save the stream position before exiting the app and resume with the same position, Why not use Shared Preferences to save. And You might also be interested to look at OnPause and OnResume states in [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).